# How do I express the "OR" logic operator in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Let's say that I want to check that one of two terms are effective, how do I express it?

```
if (value == 1 **--OR--** value == nil) {
    do something;
}
```

Comment: You mean in Objective-C, not in iOS...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`||`

eg: `if (value == 1 || value == nil)`